# Non parametric plot of $R(t)$

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, reliability

Here is the attached question from the book, introduction to reliability engineering.

> [image]

Here is the attached solution related to it, but i don't know whether it is correct or not. **I just want someone to edit or tell me how to do it or you can share some relevant source for understanding this, i don't have the book and it is not available on internet**

**Solution:**
[image]
[image]

I know there is not any non parametric plot. Can you tell m how to plot it!?